# Why won't my PHP plugin system work?

Tags: php, function, class, object, plugins

I'm trying to make a prototype of a simple plugin system I plan on implementing into one of my projects. I have 4 files:

- `Index.php`
- `Plugins/__BASE.php`
- `Plugins/Sample.php`

The index file checks if the 'oncall' method belongs to a class in the Plugins folder using functions I defined in the `Plugins` class (`__BASE.php`). If it does exist, it will execute it.

```
require_once 'Plugins/__BASE.PHP';

$func  = 'oncall';
$plugins = new Plugins();

if($plugins->IsPluginMethod($func)) {
    $obj = $plugins->GetObject($func);
    call_user_func(array($obj, $func));
}
else
    echo "'$func' isn't part of a plugin!";
```

`__BASE.php` is the base plugin class which all of the plugins will extend. It has two methods: `IsPluginMethod()` and `GetObject()`. IsPluginMethod checks if the method name supplied belongs to a class and GetObject returns an instance of the class the method belongs to.

```
class Plugins {

    public $age = "100";

    public function IsPluginMethod($func) {
        foreach(glob('*.php') as, $file) {
            if($file != '__BASE.php') {
                require_once $file;
                $class = basename($file, '.php');
                if(class_exists($class)) {
                    $obj = new $class;
                if(method_exists($obj, $func))
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
        }
    }
}

    public function GetObject($func) {
        foreach(glob('*.php') as $file) {
            if($file != '__BASE.php') {
                require_once $file;
                $class = basename($file, '.php');
                if(class_exists($class)) {
                    $obj = new $class;
                    return $obj;
                }
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Sample.php is a sample plugin which prints $this->age which is defined in the Plugins class.

```
class Sample extends Plugins {

    public function oncall() {
        echo "Age: {$this->age}";
    }
}
```

This is what I see in index.php:

```
'oncall' isn't part of a plugin!
```

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In __BASE.php file change `(glob('*.php')` to `glob('Plugins/*.php')`

Comment: Yes __BASE.php is in Plugins folder but you is included in index page which is not. it work's for me.